# IOS9: CoreSpotlight and Siri

Tags: ios, siri, corespotlight

In my IOS9 app, I am able to add data to spotlight's index using CoreSpotlight library (i.e. what I add to the index shows up when I search using the spotlight search box).

However, Siri doesn't seem to be pulling info from there. Here is my code:

```
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeText as String)
attributeSet.title = "AWS Traffic"
attributeSet.contentDescription = "AWS Server Traffic in MyCompany"
attributeSet.keywords = ["MyApp", "AWS", "Server", "Traffic"]

let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "com.mycompany.MyApp", domainIdentifier: "com.company.MyApp.AWS", attributeSet: attributeSet)

CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems([item]) { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print("Indexing error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Search item successfully indexed!")
    } 
}
```

Is there any way of getting Siri to show the indexed data from my app? Currently, when I speak to Siri with my keywords, it just does a web search.

Comment: I am experiencing the same. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

At this time, in iOS 9, Siri does not interact with the items your app adds to the Spotlight index. This API is only used to get items to appear in Spotlight Search results, not in Siri responses.